# CSS : Only one div scrollable

Tags: html, css, scroll

I am trying to have only one div to be scrollable, but I don't know to do that.

I would like for h2 and c (black and blue) to stay as they are, and only d ( pink) is scrollable.

Right now, the whole line is scrollable.

```css
.a {
   background-color:red;
   width: calc(100vw - 3rem); 
   overflow:scroll;
}

.b {
  background-color:green;
  display: inline-flex;

  height:3rem;
}

.c {
  background-color:blue;
  display: inline-flex;
  width:3rem;
  height:3rem;
}

.d {
  background-color:pink;
  display: inline-flex;
  width:133rem;
  height:3rem;
}

h2 {
  background-color:black;
  user-select: none;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.9rem;
  width: 4.1rem;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  height:3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>
    <h2></h2>
    <div class='c'></div>
    <div class='d'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: use `position:fixed;` for h2 and c it will works

Comment: @Marko What do you want actually? `vertical` or `horizontal` `scrollable` content.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

try this

```css
.a {
   background-color:red;
   width: calc(100vw - 3rem); 
   overflow:scroll;
}

.b {
  background-color:green;
  display: inline-flex;

  height:3rem;
}

.c {
  background-color:blue;
  display: inline-flex;
  width:3rem;
  height:3rem;
}

.d {
  background-color:pink;
  display: inline-flex;
  width:133rem;
  height:3rem;
}

h2 {
  background-color:black;
  user-select: none;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.9rem;
  width: 4.1rem;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  height:3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>
    <h2></h2>
    <div class='c'></div>
    <div class='d'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

```css
.a {
   background-color:red;
   width: 100%;
}

.b {
  background-color:green;
  display: flex;
  flex-wrap:wrap;
  height:3rem;
}

.c {
  background-color:blue;
  width:3rem;
  height:3rem;
}

.d {
  background-color: pink;
    width: calc(100% - 7.1rem);
    height: 3rem;
    overflow-x: auto;
}
.d div{
width: 133rem;
    overflow: auto;
    height: 3rem;
}

h2 {
  background-color:black;
  user-select: none;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.9rem;
  width: 4.1rem;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  height:3rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>
    <h2></h2>
    <div class='c'></div>
    <div class='d'><div></div></div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

use `position:fixed;` for h2 and for `.c` use `position:fixed;left:4.1rem;` because your h2 width is 4.1rem so use left:4.1rem

```css
.a {
   background-color:red;
   width: calc(100vw - 3rem); 
   overflow:scroll;
}

.b {
  background-color:green;
  display: inline-flex;

  height:3rem;
}

.c {
  background-color:blue;
  display: inline-flex;
  width:3rem;
  height:3rem;  
  position:fixed;
  left:4.1rem;
}

.d {
  background-color:pink;
  display: inline-flex;
  width:133rem;
  height:3rem;
}

h2 {
  background-color:black;
  user-select: none;
  font-weight:600;
  font-size: 1.5rem;
  height: 1.9rem;
  width: 4.1rem;
  margin-top: auto;
  margin-bottom: auto;
  height:3rem;
  position:fixed;
  left:0rem;
}
```

```html
<div class='a'>
  <div class='b'>
    <h2></h2>
    <div class='c'></div>
    <div class='d'></div>
  </div>
</div>
```